# Apple Mail App :: "Erase Junk Mail" is greyed out

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail

I'm running OS X El Capitan, and have 3 Gmail accounts signed into it. For some reason, the **Erase Junk Mail** menu option is greyed out. How can I use this option?

[image]

Comment: Excellent question. Same issue on my mbp. Might have to do with Gmail <-> Apple Mail folder mappings.

Answer (score 4):

Go to mail>preferences>junk mail>under `when junk mail arrives` make sure options #2 `move it to the Junk mailbox` is selected and this should fix your problem immediately.

Let me know if you need any help, this is what worked for me after I let my junk mail build up to over 600, which was killing me, I can understand you want it gone! Should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this option is disabled when Apple Mail is set to its default Junk settings.

One of the option groups in the settings panel for Junk is `When junk mail arrives`. By default it is set to `Mark as junk mail, but leave in my inbox`.

Changing this to `Move it to the Junk mailbox` activates the menu item you refer to.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sign that Apple Mail's built-in junk mail filtering is turned off. Go into Preferences and select the Junk Mail tab in order to turn it back on again.

Comment: Actually, Apple Mail junk mail filtering is switched on already. Any other ideas?

Comment: I suggest you check out Hoshts's answer, it may well apply to your situation.